# Python: Nested Class Inheritance

Tags: python, class, pyqt

Would it be OK to declare an instance of the sub-classed class from its Base (super?) class as I do it here:

```
if 'classB_args' in dictArg.keys() and dictArg['classB_args']:
    self['classB']=ClassA( dictArg['classB_args'] )
```

Are there any side effects of doing so? What should I be aware before moving forward. I have a feeling sooner or later something would go wrong... with cPickle , pickle or may be it would be a PyQt drag-and-dropt?.. if so then why would the problem arise?

```
class Base(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Base, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setdefault('id', -1)
        self.setdefault('name', None)
        self.setdefault('classB', None)

        if not args or len(args)==0: return
        dictArg=args[0]

        if 'classB_args' in dictArg.keys() and dictArg['classB_args']:
            self['classB']=ClassA( dictArg['classB_args'] )

    def getClassB(self):
        return self['classB']

class ClassA(Base):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not (args or kwargs):   raise Exception('you need to give me *something*!')
        super(ClassA, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setdefault('win', None)
        self.setdefault('mac', None)

myDictArg= {'id':1, 'name':'MyName', 'win':'c:/windows', 'mac': '/Volumes/mac/', 'classB_args': {'id':1, 'name':'MyProject'}}

myInstance=ClassA(myDictArg)
print myInstance.getClassB()
```

Comment: [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/174568)...

Comment: There are no nested classes in your code, so the title of your question is misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking whether it will work, the answer is yes, but I can't think of a situation where it is a good idea.  The reason is that this locks your base class down to being really only useful with `ClassA` ... I think that the solution would probably be cleaner to do something like:

```
myDictArg = {'id':1, 'name':'MyName', 'win':'c:/windows', 'mac': '/Volumes/mac/', 'classB': ClassA(id=1, name='MyProject')}
```

and forgo all of the extra `classB_args` craziness in `Base.__init__`.  It's more explicit so the user ends up knowing what to expect.

If you really don't like that, you could use the type of `self` to determine what to use rather than specifying `ClassA` directly which is a *little* better:

```
self['classB'] = type(self)(dictArg['classB_args'])
```

Now, if you derive a new class from `Base`, that will be used instead:

```
class Foo(Base): pass

instance = Foo(myDictArg)
print type(instance.getClassB())  # Foo !
```

---

a few other non-related points.

1. Don't do `x in dct.keys()` -- It's horribly inefficient in python2.x.  You can just do `x in dct` :-).
2. Generally speaking, writing simple wrappers like `getClassB` are considered "unpythonic".  You can just access the data directly in python.
3. You can rewrite the `if` clause to clean it up a little:

Here's how:

```
   if 'classB_args' in dictArg.keys() and dictArg['classB_args']:
        self['classB']=ClassA( dictArg['classB_args'] )
```

goes to:

```
   # with this, you can remove the `self.setdefault('classB', None)` statement.
   item = dictArg.get('classB_args')
   self['classB'] = type(self)(item) if item else item
```

Comment: Thanks for the terrific info!

Comment: After testing it unfortunately remains unclear to me a syntax and a purpose of type(self)(item). Would you please clarify what it is.... Thanks in advance!

Comment: `type(self)` returns the class associated with the instance.  So, for example, if you call this using subclass `classA()`, `type(self)` will be `classA`.  if you make another subclass of `Base` `ClassB` (e.g. `class ClassB(Base): ...`), then `type(self)` will be `ClassB`.

Comment: but you use it like: type(self)(item)  ...... why is there (item) that follows after type(self)?...here is your code................. type(self)(item) if item else item

Comment: `type(self)` is the class -- I'm creating an instance of that class with `type(self)(item)`.  You do the same in your code except you have  `ClassA( dictArg['classB_args'] )`.  I hope you see the parallels -- `ClassA` -> `type(self)`, `dictArg['classB_args']` -> `item`.

Comment: I would appreciate if you post an entire code with this type(self)(arg) trick implemented and working. All my attempts to run it unfortunately failed with some massive errors.